# Selector CSS para seleccionar todos los inputs menos type=submit

Tags: css, selectores-css

¡Hola!

Tengo un formulario y quiero usar un selector CSS para modificar el tamaño de todos los input menos del input type submit.

Me gustaría aplicar algo así:

```
#section3 div input:not(input[type="submit"]) {
       width: 350px;
   }
```

pero no me funciona.. ¿alguien podría decirme la forma correcta de incluir ese selector?

El selector:

```
#section3 div input {
       width: 350px;
   }
```

sí que me cambia el tamaño de los inputs, pero también lo hace con el input type submit. Sé que puedo posteriormente volver a cambiar el tamaño del input type submit.. pero me gustaría aplicarlo con un único selector en vez de estar haciendo y deshaciendo estilos.

Código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Título de la página</title>
   <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
   * {
       margin: 0px;
       font-family: arial;
   }

   #section2,
   #section3 {
       text-align: center;
   }

   #section3 div {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: top;
       width: 600px;
       height: 450px;
   }

   #section3 div form {
       text-align: left;
   }

   #section3 div form label {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 150px;
       margin-right: 1em;
       vertical-align: top;
   }

   #section3 div input:not(input[type="submit"]) {
       width: 350px;
   }

   #section3 div form textarea {
       width: 350px;
       height: 200px;
   }

</style>

<body>
   <div class="contenedor">

       <!-- SECCION 3 -->
       <section id="section3">
           <h2>Sección 3</h2>
           <div>
               <form name="Contacto" method="post" action="#">
                   <label for="nombre">Nombre y Apellidos</label>
                   <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required><br>

                   <label for="correo">Correo electrónico</label>
                   <input type="email" name="email" id="correo" required><br>

                   <label for="tel">Teléfono</label>
                   <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" pattern="[0-9]{9}"><br><br>

                   <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
                   <textarea id="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba aquí su mensaje" required></textarea><br><br>

                   <input type="submit" value="Enviar"><br>
               </form>
           </div>
       </section>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Gracias :)

Comment: Código ejecutable por si a alguien le sirve para responder: https://jsfiddle.net/mfhj53se/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El planteamiento que tenías era muy acertado, te faltaba excluir la alusión a la etiqueta `<input>` dentro del `not()`.

```css
input:not([type="submit"]) {
     width: 350px;
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo mas simple en estos casos sería que manejes la selección a través de clases y ids considerando:

- Todos los inputs de tipo (text, email, etc) pueden tener la clase `texto-ingresado`, de esta forma solo aquellos que tengan dicho atributo se verán afectados por el CSS declarado
- El input de tipo `submit` le podemos dar un id `envio` considerando que es un elemento con una funcionalidad totalmente distinta a los demás ya mencionados y lo podemos identificar dentro del form de forma única

De manera que si por ejemplo a tu HTML lo dejas así:

```
<form name="Contacto" method="post" action="#">
  <label for="nombre">Nombre y Apellidos</label>
    <input class="texto-ingresado" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required><br>
  <label for="correo">Correo electrónico</label>
    <input class="texto-ingresado" type="email" name="email" id="correo" required><br>
  <label for="tel">Teléfono</label>
    <input class="texto-ingresado" type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" pattern="[0-9]{9}"><br><br>
  <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
    <textarea id="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba aquí su mensaje" required></textarea><br><br>
  <input id="envio" type="submit" value="Enviar"><br>
</form>
```

Entonces tus reglas de selección se pueden componer de esta forma:

```
<style>
  .texto-ingresado {
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  #envio {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias opciones para solucionar esto: Puedes utilizar selectores basados en las propiedades de los inputs que quieres modificar:

```
input[type="email"], input[type="text"]{ /*Todos los inputs de tipo text o email van a ser afectados*/
background-color: red;
}
```

Puedes usar clases como han dicho en otras respuestas, y más. Te recomiendo que leas esta documentación ya que te puede servir mucho.

**Documentación:**

[Pseudo selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

[Selector CSS por atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo)